# Strip WordPress gallery shortcode from the_content and use outside the loop

Tags: wordpress, gallery, shortcode, caption

I'd like to be able to strip the wordpress gallery shortcode from the_content, but then use the shortcode again outside of the loop.

I'm currently striping the shortcode in the functions.php using:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'strip_shortcodes');
```

And then using it outside the loop in my template with:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery"]'); ?>
```

This works great except it strips all shortcodes including the caption shortcode that I need to use in the post.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can get around this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

```
// Remove gallery from content
add_filter('the_content', 'strip_shortcode_gallery');
function strip_shortcode_gallery( $content ) {
    preg_match_all( '/'. get_shortcode_regex() .'/s', $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER );
    if ( ! empty( $matches ) ) {
        foreach ( $matches as $shortcode ) {
            if ( 'gallery' === $shortcode[2] ) {
                $pos = strpos( $content, $shortcode[0] );
                if ($pos !== false)
                    return substr_replace( $content, '', $pos, strlen($shortcode[0]) );
            }
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: This should have more upvotes.  I have read through several different ways to strip the gallery shortcode, and this is definitely the most concise!  Works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: =/ The only issue is that this also removes all content styling, like <p> and <br>